# How to click on element which is cloned, in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image] [image]

Please check the image where I need to click on Start trial button, which is in cycle mode, by clicking right arrow or left arrow, I will be getting this multiple times with other options.

```
 form method="post" name="" action="http://dev-imaginovation.net/100s-happiness/www-100s-happiness/virtualclasspay">
<input id="pkg_id" type="hidden" value="3" name="pkg_id"/>
<input id="pkg_price" type="hidden" value="0" name="pkg_price"/>
<div class="virtualplan_box">
<div class="virtualplanHeader">Free Package</div>
<div class="virtualplanContent">
<h3>Free Subscription</h3>
<p>Check one of our On-the-Go Virtual Classes free of charge!</p>
<div class="virtualplanprice">
<div id="virtual_description" class="learn-more getstart-btn wow zoomIn clearfix animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: zoomIn;">
<a class="fr-btn orange-color-bg white-color purchase-btn" name="submit_plan" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(247, 144, 73);" href="http://dev-imaginovation.net/100s-happiness/www-100s-happiness/freevirtualclass">Start Trial</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 670px; margin-right: 0px;">
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 670px; margin-right: 0px;">
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 670px; margin-right: 0px;">
<div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 670px; margin-right: 0px;">
<div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 670px; margin-right: 0px;">
```

Comment: plz post the source code as well

Comment: did you bind your click event to the button after you cloned it?

Comment: you can see 3 matching nodes at the bottom where it is repeated in the attached image

Comment: Hey nic there is an issue with the locator you have identified, it is giving 3 matching nodes. All 3 of them has same xpath. Can you tell us which one specifically are you looking for (1, 2 or 3). Please share the relevant HTML as well if possible.

Comment: Hi pArAs, I am looking for the 1st one. Let me check and send the code

Comment: U can see the code where it has been repeated 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below xpath with index :-

```
// for first element
(//div[@id = 'virtual_description']/a)[1]

// for second element
(//div[@id = 'virtual_description']/a)[2]

// for third element
(//div[@id = 'virtual_description']/a)[3]
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: thanks for the reply Omi, but its not working - displays element not visible even though i am able to view the button on the screen

Comment: @nic.jess did u try this xpath to locate element on firepath???.. ensure it first..if you locate that element which you want then try to find element with WebDriverWait..

Comment: Yes, but the button is not getting highlighted when i keep the xpathgiven by you in Firepath

Comment: remove inverted commas... paste only (//div[@id = 'virtual_description']/a)[1]

Comment: ofcourse Omi, I have done the same, but still the button does not get highlighted

Comment: Do you think we need to provide:
 driver.findElement(By.tagName("form"));
 before writing code for Start trial button

Comment: No, I think there is no need... but if that element which you want to find inside a frame..you need to switch frame before find element...If you able to provided me website link..please provide..I will solve your problem..

Comment: Omi, i got it, i had debugged in google chrome, it was element 2, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#virtual_description[style*='visibility: visible']>a.fr-btn"));

    for(int i=0;i<elem.size();i++){
        try {
            if(elem.get(i).isDisplayed()){//u can try isEnabled() here
                elem.get(i).click();
                break;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {             
            continue;
        }

    }
```

hope this works.

Comment: Hi noor, thanks for the reply, but the code given by you also does not work
check the reponse below:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div#virtual_description[style='visibility: visible']>a.fr-btn"}

Comment: Sorry, even the new one doesn't work. Can you please check the code. Do you think we need to provide:
 driver.findElement(By.tagName("form"));
 before writing code for Start trial button

Comment: can u please do it for me....just open it in chrome...after open the start trial box, inspect it using right click, than press cntrl+f, there write div#virtual_description[style*='visibility: visible']>a.fr-btn and pls let me know how many suggestion it gives

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113720/discussion-between-noor-and-nic-jess).